# How to stop GDB from executing "break main" by default in Eclipse?

Tags: c, eclipse, gdb, break

I'm working on a C project with Eclipse and MinGW. When running a debug build of this project, gdb always breaks on entering `main()`. I can see why this could be useful, but for my current project I don't want that to happen.

I've read that there is a command

```
(gdb) break main
```

which will accomplish the same behavior when running from the command line.

At the moment I do NOT have a .gdbinit file.

At the moment gdb doesn't stop on entering main when running from the command line, but it does when running from Eclipse.

How do I make GDB stop breaking on entering main by default within Eclipse?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Make sure you are in the c++ perspective, then go to menu `Run` -> `Debug Configurations`. Make sure your application is chosen in the left pane, press the `Debugger` tab, and uncheck `Stop on startup at:` checkbox.

EDIT: you can see a screen-shot here: [Method/Function Breakpoints in Eclipse CDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119066/method-function-breakpoints-in-eclipse-cdt/4177895#4177895)

Comment: This is settings is for single run configuration. What if I would like to set it globally for all projects for ever?

Comment: Note: The Debugger tab only appears for me during debugging. So I had to start the debug, wait for it to break in main(), then follow the steps above, and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

To set it for any new launch, On the menu **Window->Preferences**, Select **C/C++->Debug->GDB** item on the left, and then go to the **Debug Configurations Defaults** section and uncheck the "**Stop at startup at:**" checkbox on CDT 8.0 or later.

You can see the details here: [How do I prevent the debugger from stopping on the first line?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#How_do_I_prevent_the_debugger_from_stopping_on_the_first_line.3F)