# Eclipse cdt/gdb automatic breakpoint on program entry - how to disable?

Tags: gdb, eclipse-cdt, breakpoints

I am using eclipse cdt to develop a c++ program. One thing that drives me crazy is that either eclipse cdt or gdb which it uses for debugging break automatically on main method entry. I don't want to break there!

Before I had some problems and had to recreate my project from scratch, I managed to disable this feature (I think) but for the life of me I cannot find it now! Problems seems to be the eight million different places where debug settings can be found in eclipse.

Does anyone know how to disable this?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278532/how-to-stop-gdb-from-executing-break-main-by-default-in-eclipse/4296624#4296624

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to Run / Debug Configurations / Debugger / Stop on startup at: [main]