# Stop eclipse CDT from debugging from main()?

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-cdt, program-entry-point

If I debug my C++ code using eclipse CDT, it appears that it always starts the debugging process from the `main()` function, even though there is no breakpoint at the beginning of the `main()`.

Is there a way to have eclipse CDT start to debug from the first breakpoint rather than `main()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop GDB from executing "break main" by default in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278532/how-to-stop-gdb-from-executing-break-main-by-default-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 20):

On the menu **Run -> Debug Configurations**, right click the **C/C++ Applications** item on the left, and create **New** configuration. Go to the Debugger tab and uncheck the **Stop on startup at** checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open "Debug Configurations" GUI
2. Choose your application
3. Select "Debugger" tab
4. **Uncheck** "Stop on startup at main"

[image]