# Eclipse automatically adds breakpoint at main method

Tags: c++, eclipse, breakpoints

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to stop GDB from executing “break main” by default in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278532/how-to-stop-gdb-from-executing-break-main-by-default-in-eclipse)

I decided to learn C++ (because Java isn't as good at certain things) so I wrote a (VERY) simple program.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "This is a test" << endl;
    int test = 100;
    cout << test << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It worked as expected, but Eclipse seems to be adding an automatic breakpoint at the `main` method:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/HD1KxlX.png]

How can I stop this automatic breakpoint insertion?

Comment: @RobKennedy Yep, thanks, this is the first time I close-voted my own question :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an option in the debug configuration that allows you to *Stop on startup at* (or simillar), which is enabled by default. Disable it.